# How do I install Atom editor and start it without sudo?

Tags: apt, dpkg, root, atom

I have tried installing Atom editor on Ubuntu 14.04 . Whenever I installed it, either by downloading the `/.deb` or by adding this `ppa:webupd8team/atom`, I cannot start Atom without sudo.

It shows the following error on terminal while not starting with `sudo`:

```
/usr/bin/atom: line 104: /home/myhome/.atom/nohup.out: Permission denied

(atom:3947): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/myhome/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

I also tried installing with non-root access through the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --install --force-not-root --root=$HOME atom-amd64.deb
```

It shows the following error:

```
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory
```

But it works if I remove the non-root parameters `--force-not-root --root=$HOME`

Anyone knows how to install Atom with non-root access on Ubuntu successfully?

Comment: Can you check what `ls -dl /home/myhome/.atom` says?

Comment: It's owned by `myhome` as well.

Comment: did you install atom as root user?

Comment: Yes. I installed as a root user.

Comment: you shouldn't do that. i know hardly any software that should be installed as root.  this is mostl likely why it doesn't work. If you install something as root, it belongs to user root and group root - none other will be able to execute it.

Comment: @Gewure that's a misleading comment - we generally install software as root, and most programs have read and execute permission for all users.

Comment: A little. You dont install as root but with roots rights. Installing as root leads to root:root ownership, which locks out every user.

Comment: @Gewure nope. With root rights = as root. Check the ownership of the files you know and love in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`...

Answer (score 1):

Delete ppa and all previous file related to the installation (and obliously disinstall it) and then try to install by the [official page](https://atom.io/) and instead of use shell use your desktop enviroment.

Sounds like you've installed atom for "root" user and not for your user.

Comment: As I said in my post, i have done that. It didn't work.

Comment: Yes , I read that you've done it yet, but there're two option: 
1) bad installation
2) bad path settings on your  machine

So try first to do a clean installation as I wrote and then try to gave atom permission with `sudo chmod 666` (it's not a good way but it might work)

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands to quickly and easily install and upgrade the Atom text editor snap package from the terminal in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu (64-bit only).

- Install Atom text editor:

  ```
  sudo apt install snapd  
  sudo snap install --classic atom
  ```

  Note that a snap in classic confinement behaves as a traditionally packaged application with full access to the system, and Atom extension packages are installed into the user's home directory.
- Upgrade Atom text editor:

  ```
  sudo snap refresh --classic atom
  ```
- Run Atom text editor:

  ```
  snap run atom
  ```